# multidimensional array with random matrix neighbor in C

Tags: arrays, c, matrix, multidimensional-array

I want to check the values of the user-selected cell in the random matrix. right, left, up, I want to check on your neighbors downstairs. if the value in the selected cell is a value greater than the values in neighboring cells, I want to print the letter R in red. if the value in the selected cell is less than and/or equal to its neighbors, I want to print green, i.e. the letter G. I'm having trouble printing R and G to The Matrix.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
 
int main(){
    int a, b, i, j,k,l;
    int array1[i][j], array2[i][j];
    
    
    printf("enter Matrix line number: ");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("enter the number of Matrix columns:");
    scanf("%d", &b);
    
    int matrix[a][b], matrix2[b][a];
    
    for(i=0; i<a; i++) 
    {
        
    }
      for(int i=0; i<a; i++)
        for(int j=0; j<b; j++){
            array1[i][j] = rand() % 10+1; 
            array2[i][j] = rand() % 10+1; 
            
        }
    printf("\nOur matrix:\n");
    for(int i=0; i<a; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<b; j++){
            printf("%3d ", array2[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    
    printf("select a cell from The Matrix:\n");
    printf("Senter the line of The Matrix you are selecting:\n");
    scanf ("%d",&k);
    printf ("enter the column of The Matrix you are selecting:\n");
    scanf("%d",&l);
    int p=array2[k][l];
    int r=array2[k-1][l];
    int m=array2[k][l-1];
    int n=array2[k+1][l];
    int s=array2[k][l+1];
    if(p>r && p>n && p>s && p>m)
    {
        
        printf("The cell you enter is larger than all its neighbors.\n");
        char S=array2[k][l];
        S='R';
        printf("%3d", array2[k][l]);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("The cell you enter is smaller than its neighbors and / or has a value equal to its neighbors.\n");
        char S=array2[k][l];
        S='G';
        printf("%3d", array2[k][l]);
    }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i and j are uninitialized in 'int array1[i][j]'. Fix it

Comment: I don't think that's the only problem. and I'm having trouble printing the matrix in red(R) and green(G), not creating a matrix.

Comment: Please enable compiler warnings

Comment: You assign the character 'R' or 'G' to the local variable `S`, not the array.

Comment: I am not getting an error or warning

Comment: how can I do it

Comment: `i` and `j` are uninitialized when you declare `array1` and `array2` here: `int array1[i][j], array2[i][j];` . Therefore `array1` and `array2` have random sizes depending on what garbage values there was in memory for `i` and `j`. You need to assign values to `i` and `j` before creating the variable length arrays (VLAs) `array1` and `array2`.

Answer (score 0):

There's a quite few problems with your code. Namely: the use of uninitialized values, failure to perform bounds checks, and the misunderstanding of copy-by-value.

When you have a function like

```
void foo(void) {
    int a;
    printf("%d\n", a);
}
```

the variable `a` is never initialized. It contains whatever data was existing on the stack beforehand - i.e., garbage. You should always give your variables value before using them.

This section of code

```
int p=array2[k][l];
int r=array2[k-1][l];
int m=array2[k][l-1];
int n=array2[k+1][l];
int s=array2[k][l+1];
```

contains several instances where you would step too far in one direction, accessing memory you shouldn't (i.e., when `k == 0, j == 0`, `array[k - 1][l]` tries to access `array[-1][0]` which is out of bounds.) You need to take care in making sure you're only looking where you are allowed (this goes hand-in-hand with validating user input).

When you do

```
char S=array2[k][l];
S='R';
```

you are *copying* the value found in `array2[k][l]` to the local variable `char S`. You then change the local value - this does **not** update the value found at `array2[k][l]`.

Other than that, you have a lot of "extra" code that doesn't actually do anything. You should try not to leave erroneous, or unused code lying around. Clean formatting is also key to being able to easily read the flow of your program.

---

The core of this program can be broken down into several steps.

- Seed our random number generator.
- Accept and validate user input: *X* & *Y*.
- Create an integer matrix using: *X* & *Y*.

  - Populate the integer matrix with random values.
- Create a red/green matrix using: *X* & *Y*.

  - Populate the red/green matrix based on values found in the integer matrix.
- Display our data.

Here is a simple, working program. Note the lengths we go to making sure our array access is within bounds. I'll leave it up to you to figure out how to take user input to view a single cell (there should be enough hints in this).

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int in_range(int value, int lower, int upper) {
    return value >= lower && value <= upper;
}

char get_cell_color(int x, int y, int max_x, int max_y, int m[max_x][max_y]) {
    int v = m[x][y];
    int n = -1, s = -1, e = -1, w = -1;

    /* change from logical "size", to maximum "index" */
    max_x -= 1;
    max_y -= 1;

    if (in_range(x, 1, max_x))
        n = m[x - 1][y];
    if (in_range(x, 0, max_x - 1))
        s = m[x + 1][y];

    if (in_range(y, 0, max_y - 1))
        e = m[x][y + 1];
    if (in_range(y, 1, max_y))
        w = m[x][y - 1];

    return (v > n && v > s && v > e && v > w) ? 'R' : 'G';
}

int main(void) {
    int x = 0, y = 0;

    srand(time(NULL));

    while (!in_range(x, 1, 10) || !in_range(y, 1, 10)) {
        printf("Enter X: ");
        scanf("%d", &x);
        printf("Enter Y: ");
        scanf("%d", &y);
    }

    int matrix[x][y];

    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < y; j++)
            matrix[i][j] = rand() % 10 + 1;

    char rg_matrix[x][y];

    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < y; j++)
            rg_matrix[i][j] = get_cell_color(i, j, x, y, matrix);

    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        printf("[ ");
        for (int j = 0; j < y; j++)
            printf("\033[%dm%02d ",
                    (rg_matrix[i][j] == 'R' ? 31 : 32),
                    matrix[i][j]);
        printf("\033[0m]\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you very much, but I want the element in the matrix to be selected by the user. and don't colorful. enter the value I will compare with its neighbors as rows and columns from the keyboard. for example user entered 3, 2. value 3.row 2.column. is value larger compare the neighbours? yes. then delete that value in the matrix. write R instead. isn't it ? write G.

Comment: @BS That's all very well, but it is up to you to implement that in your own program. The program I've shown should provide ample source of hints on how to approach the problem. Stack Overflow is not a coding service. Additionally, I would carefully consider what issues could be caused by "deleting" data your future calculations may depend upon. Remember, the way you display data does not have to be exactly the same as how you store it.

Comment: I am grateful for your nice thoughts, ideas and advice.